Desktop login compromised since 'upgrade' on 1 April?
I have Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome.  There was an 'upgrade' (haha!) on 1 April.  After this my logins often give a frozen screen, which goes dark after about 40sec and then reappears, unfrozen, after another 10 sec.
There was another 'upgrade' on 7 April, but nothing since.
This morning, my boot led to an auto-login, although I never enabled this!
What is going on?  Some malware?
